# Подключение переносимой библиотеки к Android Studio

Tags: java, android, c#, visual-studio, android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте.

Создал проект **Библиотека классов (переносимая для iOS, Android и Windows)** в Visual Studio 2015 Community. Пишется на C#.

Скриншот для наглядности.

После сборки такого проекта в Debug/Release падают 2 файла *.dll и *.pdb и ещё dll от Newsoft.JSON для десериализации.

Будет ли эта библиотека работать под Android Studio или она заточена только под Visual Studio и Xamarin?
Если будет, то как такой проект подключить (или как правильно собрать), чтобы оно работало и использовалось в проекте на Android Studio.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же в моём проекте какие-то не такие настройки, то был бы благодарен, если подскажите как настроить проект для моих целей.
Хотелось бы, чтобы библиотека работала под следующими платформами (проектами): Android (Android Studio), Windows Form, WPF, Windows Phone, UWP.

P.S.: В ASP.NET потребности нет, он сам добавляется в таргет из-за схожести в API. Поддержка iOS не преследуется, но если её можно добавить малыми усилиями, то почему бы и нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio предназначена исключительно для нативной разработки и работает только с Java и другими JVM языками, при наличии соответствующего плагина для Android.

Переносимые библиотеки классов -- это технология .NET и не существует возможности интегрировать её с нативным Java кодом с помощью Android Studio.

Однако, если Вы используете Xamarin, то Вам не нужна Android Studio для создания Android-приложений. Вы можете создавать приложения на C# под все платформы, используя только Visual Studio (или Xamarin Studio). Соответственно, другие люди также смогут воспользоваться Вашей библиотекой, но только используя .NET Framework или Xamarin, но никак не Java и Android Studio.

Comment: вся беда в том, что я пишу библиотеку.. и под Windows. Под Android пишет другой человек и он работает в Android Studio. =(
Visual studio и Xamarin позволяют писать под Android на C# вроде. А на той же Java можно писать в них?

Comment: @Mr.Modest Да, Visual studio и Xamarin позволяют писать под Android на C#. Собственно, именно для этого Xamarin нужен, чтобы писать на одном языке сразу под несколько платформ.
Если Вы хотите выделить общий код для Android и Windows проекта, то у Вас есть несколько вариантов.
1) Писать всё на Java, в том числе и десктоп приложение.
2) Писать всё на .NET, тогда Вашему Android-разработчику надо будет перейти на использование Xamarin
3) Писать общий код на С/С++ и скомпилировать библиотеку под ARM с помощью Android NDK (вряд ли Вам это надо).